# Infill missing variables of a df from a list

Tags: r, dplyr

I have missing categorical variables in a list. I would like to add all the combinations of these classifications to the data frame using `complete`. I can do this for a single variable using `mutate`.
**Simplified example:**

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a1 = 1:6,
             b1 = rep(c(1,2),3),
             c1 = rep(c(1:3), 2))

missing_cols <- list(d1 = c(7:8),
                     e1 = c(12:14))

# Use the first classification of d1 for mutate and complete with all classifications
df %>% 
  mutate(!!names(missing_cols)[1] := missing_cols[[1]][1]) %>% 
  complete(nesting(a1, b1,c1), d1 = missing_cols[[1]])
```

**Desired output**

```
df %>% 
  mutate(!!names(missing_cols)[1] := missing_cols[[1]][1]) %>% 
  mutate(!!names(missing_cols)[2] := missing_cols[[2]][1]) %>% 
  complete(nesting(a1, b1,c1), d1 = missing_cols[[1]], e1 = missing_cols[[2]])
```

This will get the correct output for d1. How can I do this for all variables in my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `crossing` with `cross_df` :

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(df, cross_df(missing_cols))

#      a1    b1    c1    d1    e1
#   <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     1     7    12
# 2     1     1     1     7    13
# 3     1     1     1     7    14
# 4     1     1     1     8    12
# 5     1     1     1     8    13
# 6     1     1     1     8    14
# 7     2     2     2     7    12
# 8     2     2     2     7    13
# 9     2     2     2     7    14
#10     2     2     2     8    12
# … with 26 more rows
```

`cross_df` creates all possible combination of `missing_cols` while `crossing` takes that output and creates all possible combination with `df`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `expand.grid`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(df, expand.grid(missing_cols))
```